# Access another database from same server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do you access another database from same server? Got server name using SELECT @@SERVERNAME, and then did servername.dbo.mydatabasename.mytablename but query analyzer says Invalid object name. Any ideas? Am doing

```
insert into Myservername.Mydatabasename.Mytablename
(Email,Username1)
Values
('h','h')
```

Using MS SQL Server 2008, on same server

Comment: Can you post the exact message you got in query analyzer?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks for replies guys!squillman was correct, dbo was incorrectly positioned in the fqn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using MS SQL Server, fully qualified references are in the form:

```
[servername].[databasename].[schema].[object]
```

On the same server you do not need the `[servername]` reference.

In your case, you reversed the `databasename` and `schema`.  It should be:

`servername.mydatabasename.dbo.mytablename`

Your INSERT should look like:

```
insert into Mydatabasename.Schema.Mytablename
(Email,Username1)
Values ('h','h')
```

(probably your Schema here is dbo)

You would include the `[servername]` component when performing an operation across a linked server in which case `[servername]` would be the name of the linked server, which incidentally may not actually be the the same as the hostname/instance name of the remote server.

Answer (score 2):

Is it not rather `mydatabasename.DBO.mytablename` ? And if your database is on the same server, you normally don't have to use the `servername`.

Answer (score 2):

Should be

```
insert into Myservername.Mydatabasename.MySchema.Mytablename
  (Email,Username1)
Values
  ('h','h')
```

Though as you're on the same server you don't need `Myservername`. In your example which was using three part notation it would have assumed that `Mydatabasename` was the schema; hence the error